# examples with not periodic functions

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for examples of non-periodic functions $f\in C^{\infty}$   satifying $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq 1 \forall n\in \mathbb{N},\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

I know only examples with periodic functions as sin(x) or cos(x)

edit 
Thank you so much . If I suppose moreover that there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f′(a)=1$, 
I think that f is necessarily defined by $f(x)=sin(x−a)$

Comment: I suspect a function like $e^{-cx^2}$ with $c$ small enough might work.  Also note that $f$ must be everywhere analytic, which restricts where to look.

Comment: Please ask the part about whether $f'(a) = 1$ while $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq 1$ for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ and all $x\in\mathbb R$ implies $f(x)=\sin(x-a)$ as a separate question, rather than adding it on after the question is answered.

Comment: Your $\mathbb N$ contains $0$, right?  Some take it to start at $1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{\pi}\right) $$
? That is not a periodic function, and every derivative is clearly bounded by $1$ in absolute value.

$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n^2}\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right) $$
works just as well.

Comment: Thank you so much . If I suppose moreover that there exists $a\in \R$ such that f′(a)=1 , I think that f is necessarily defined by f(x)=sin(x−a)

Comment: @ Jack Can you give me a counter example ?

Comment: How about $f(x)=x$?  There are certainly points with derivative $1$, it is infinitely differentiable (and all derivatives are bounded).

Comment: @jack ur example is bad you must have $|f(x)|\leq 1$

Comment: @Tina: Also, have a look at bump functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: @jack I am not convinced that   your function satisfying  $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq 1$

Comment: @Tina: anyway, I have provided an explicit counter-example in my updated answer.

Comment: For the first question it it's ok . My second question is if $f\in C^{\infty}$   satifying $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq 1 \forall n\in \mathbb{N},\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f'(0)=1$ i think that $f(x)=sin(x)$

Comment: Thank you I will look your examples

Comment: Jack: Bump functions can't work because such $f$ is analytic due to the uniform bound on derivatives of all orders.  So your construction above won't work. It isn't obvious to me how you could modify your examples to get derivative $1$ at some point. The sine integral function isn't bounded by $1$.  It isn't obvious Tina's conjecture is false, but I agree it is a different question.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: good point. I was keep thinking "we may shape a $C^{\infty}$ function in any way we like" but $C^{\omega}$ functions are more rigid. Taking back my comments, I am not sure now.

Comment: The modified sine integral $$ \frac{\text{Si}(\text{Si}(\pi) x)}{\text{Si}(\pi)} $$ fulfills $f'(0)=1$ and $|f(x)|\leq 1$ but at some point the derivatives get large. Maybe there is some simple way to fix this issue.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks.

Comment: I was given a very complicated proof of my question 2 using the complex analysis. The proof is spread over 4 pages. Can you give me a simple proof please? http://www.math.sciences.univ-nantes.fr/~nicoleau/sinus.pdf

Comment: @all No chance of having a simple proof?

Comment: @Tina: Please ask it as a different question.

Comment: ok good idea http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197387/characterization-of-the-sinus