# Characterization of the sinus

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am looking for a simple proof of this result:

> If  $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ fulfills $f'(0)=1$ and $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq 1$  for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, then $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

A proof (through the Paley-Wiener theorem and complex analysis) can be found here: 
http://www.math.sciences.univ-nantes.fr/~nicoleau/sinus.pdf

Comment: I don't think there is any easy proof of this characterization. Your ${\Bbb N}$ contains btw zero (the French notation).

Comment: Yes for n=0,1,2,....

Comment: @Tina Are you a French speaker? There was an article some time ago in the RMS dedicated to this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This approach should do the job nicely. $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ ensures $f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, hence we may assume that

$$f(x) = k_0 + s_1 \sin(x)+c_1 \cos(x)+\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(c_n \cos(nx)+ s_n\sin(nx)\right) \tag{1}$$
holds for any $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$. Since $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq 1$ we have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^{(n)}(x)^2\,dx \leq 2\pi$.
On the other hand, by Parseval's theorem, for any $m\geq 1$ we have

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^{(m)}(x)^2\,dx = \pi(s_1^2+c_1^2)+\pi\sum_{n\geq 2}n^{2m}(c_n^2+s_n^2) \tag{2}$$
hence in order that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f^{(m)}(x)^2\,dx \leq 2\pi$ for any $m\geq 1$ we need to have
$$ \forall n\geq 2,\qquad c_n=s_n=0.\tag{3} $$
This proves$^{(*)}$ the only functions fulfilling our constraints are functions of the form $f(x)=k_0+s_1 \sin(x)+c_1\cos(x)$. By imposing $f'(0)=1$ we get $s_1=1$ and by further imposing $\left|f(x)\right|\leq 1$ we get $k_0=c_1=0$ as wanted.

$(*)$ On the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. On the other hand the constraints imply that $f$ is an entire function, hence once $f$ is defined on $(-\pi,\pi)$ it can be prolongated in a unique way to the whole real line.
Or you may apply the same argument over and over, first on $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$, then on $L^2(-2\pi,2\pi)$, then on $L^2(-4\pi,4\pi)$, $\ldots$, concluding that $f(x)=\sin(x)$ over any interval of the form $(-2^N\pi,2^N\pi)$, i.e. on the whole real line.

In the comments below Bob Pego makes an important observation: in order to grant that the Fourier series of $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the formal $n$-th derivative of the Fourier series of $f(x)$ some assumption on the decay of $s_n,c_n$ has to be made. Luckily, the Paley-Wiener theorem grants that they have an exponential decay. Unluckily, we are not really dodging that crucial step.

The idea is freely stolen from the [Turàn power sums inequality](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2154701?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

<sub>Problem solving is really instructing. Before looking at a proof of this fact I was believing it was wrong, and I tried constructing (non-working) counter-examples like $f(x)=\frac{\text{Si}(\text{Si}(\pi x))}{\text{Si}(\pi)}$. After many failed attempts, I convinced myself the claim was correct. Then I saw the proof through Paley-Wiener, and believed it was the most efficient way for proving the statement. The last *step back* I took was to exhibit this simple proof through Fourier series. Thank you, David Hilbert, because reflexive spaces are a bless.</sub>

Comment: I will read carefully your proof, it is very interesting. thank you very much Jack

Comment: @Tina: you're welcome, and sorry for the mess I made before, when believing the claim was incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, but (2) does not follow from (1). The Fourier series (1) is $2\pi$-periodic and represents the $2\pi$-periodic extension of $f$ from $(-\pi,\pi)$, and it cannot be differentiated term by term to represent $f^{(m)}$ in general. If it happens that $\delta=f(\pi)-f(-\pi)\ne0$ for example then $\pi s_n = \delta/n+ O(1/n^2)$. The argument here only works if $f$ is assumed to be $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: @BobPego: this works, indeed. This approach shows that $f(x)=\sin(x)$ over $(-\pi,\pi)$, and since $f(x)$ is an analytic function, this proves that $f(x)=\sin(x)$ over the whole real line.

Comment: @BobPego : $f$ and the Fourier series are equal on $(-\pi;\pi)$, don't you think the derivatives also coincide on $(-\pi;\pi)$ ? Now it is not completely obvious that $f=k+s \sin + c \cos$ on $(-\pi;\pi)$ imply that $f=k+s \sin + c \cos$ on the real line but this is a consequence of the fact that $f$ can be prolongated in an entire function.

Comment: If i understand your proof right you only need $|f'|\leq 1$ to get $c_n$, $s_n=0$ $\forall n \geq 2$ and then you only need analycity of $f$ over the real line to deduce that $f=\sin$ (and $f'(0)=1$ and $|f|\leq 1$) . This sounds even more troubling than the first result.

Comment: The function $f(x)=x$ is entire and equal to its Fourier series on $(-\pi,\pi)$. By the logic developed so far, the proof should work for this function.

Comment: @Renart: I am using that every derivative is bounded by $1$ to deduce that $c_,s_n=0$ for any $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ah yes you're right, nevermind !

Comment: @BobPego: the Fourier series of $f(x)=x$ does not converge uniformly, together with every derivative, to $f^{(n)}(x)$. So we are not allowed to state that the Fourier series of $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the formal $n$-th derivative of the Fourier series of $f(x)$.

Comment: @BobPego: but you make a good point: I am exploiting that fact that the coefficients $c_n,s_n$ have an exponential decay, due to the Paley-Wiener theorem (and so I am allowed to state that the formal derivative of a Fourier series is the Fourier series of the derivative). So I am not really dodging that crucial step.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's right, and it's why I'm saying that (2) does not evidently follow from the hypotheses. To be more explicit, if $\delta=f(\pi)-f(-\pi)\ne0$ then $$\pi s_n = \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin nx\,dx = \left.-f(x)\frac{\cos nx}n\right|_{-\pi}^\pi + O(1/n^2) = (-1)^{n+1}\delta/n+O(1/n^2),$$ even if $f$ is entire. The Parseval formula does not hold due to discontinuities in the $2\pi$-periodic extension of $f$ from $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: @BobPego: you're absolutely correct and I improved my previous answer. Is there some answer of yours I may give a (+1) to, as a token of gratitude for your contribute?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No worries - it's enough I got to learn about this lovely Paley-Wiener argument thanks to @Tina!

Comment: @Jack tank you so much. Now i can write >If  $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\exists M>0, \exists a\in \mathbb{R},\exists p\in \mathbb{N^*}$ / $f^{(p)}(a)=M$, and $|f^{(n)}(x)|\leq M$  for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, then $f(x)=M\sin(x-a+(p-1)\frac {\pi}{2}))$.

Comment: @Tina: you're welcome, and I guess you are right. Interesting question.

Comment: @Jack we can proof  an exponential decay without the Paley-Wiener theorem, By the Taylor formula applied to the point x $f(x+iy)=\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{f^{(k)}(x)}{k!}(iy)^{k}$ thus $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : \vert f(x+iy) \vert \leq e^{\vert y\vert }$

Answer (score 0):

This proof gives a comprehensive proof in the periodic case. It is not true that the periodized restriction of an analytic function on any bounded interval (even if the values of the function are the same at each endpoint of the segment) is smooth... 
 And it is not true that the use of Paley-Wiener Theorem gives the best way to deal with this exercise as well!
There are many "elementary" proofs of these results even perturbative one...