# Show that $f(z) = C \cdot \sin(\pi z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)| \leq K e^{\pi |\text{Im}(z)|}$ for some $K > 0$, and that $f(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $f(z) = C \cdot \sin (\pi z)$.

I have seen very similar problems on here asking this question with (what I think is) a stronger assumption. That is, assuming $f(z+1) = -f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. The argument itself is an application of Liouville's theorem. But with only assuming that $f(n) = 0$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ I am not able to recreate the argument.

Bounding the function $g(z) = f(z)/\sin(\pi z)$ on a strip like $|\text{Im}(y)| \geq 1$ comes down to bounding the sine function from below on this region. However we cannot do the same for $|\text{Im}(y)| \leq 1$. How can I proceed?

Here is the link to the post I mentioned above: [Show that $f(z) = c \sin (\pi z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318802/show-that-fz-c-sin-pi-z).

Comment: Hint: $g$ is actually bounded outside $B(\mathbb{Z},1/4)$. You can mimic the Liouville argument by picking the right loop to use Cauchy’s integral formula.

Comment: @Aphelli: Sorry that I am not familiar with the notation $B(\mathbb{Z},1/4)$. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: $B(\mathbb{Z},1/4)$ refers to these complex numbers which are at distance at most $1/4$ from $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *idea* is that $|\sin(z)|$ is not only bounded below for $|\operatorname{Im}(z)| \ge c > 0$, but also on the lines $\operatorname{Re}(z) = (k+1/2)\pi$ for all integers $k$.

Consider the rectangles
$$
 R_n = \{ x+ iy \mid -n-\frac 12 \le x \le n + \frac 12, -n \le y \le n \}
$$
where $n$ is a positive integer, and note that
$$
 |\sin(x+iy)|^2 = \sin^2(x) + \sinh^2(y) 
$$
for $x, y \in \Bbb R$.

On those parts of the boundary of $R_n$ with $|y| \ge 1/\pi$ you can proceed as in the referenced answer:
$$
|\sin(\pi z)| \ge |\sinh( \pi y)| \ge \frac 14 e^{\pi |y|}
$$
and therefore
$$
 |g(z)| = \frac{|f(z)|}{|\sin(\pi z)|} \le 4 K \, .
$$
And on those parts of the boundary of $R_n$ with $|y| \le 1/\pi$ is $x=\pm(n + 1/2)$ so that
$$
|\sin(\pi z)| \ge |sin(\pi x)| = 1
$$
and therefore
$$
 |g(z)| = \frac{|f(z)|}{|\sin(\pi z)|} \le e K \, .
$$

Using the maximum modulus principle it follows that $|g(z)| \le 4K$ in every rectangle $R_n$, so that $g$ is bounded in $\Bbb C$, and consequently, constant.

Comment: Using the MMP to conclude is a lot cleaner than the idea I had.